# nodejs axios JSON with Objects under the same name

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios

So, My JS Looks Like This

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node
    
    var axios = require("axios");
    var chalk = require("chalk");
    var columnify = require('columnify')
    var lineBreak = '-----------------------'
    
    
    const info_url = `https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/22663`
    
    axios.get(info_url, { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } }).then(anime => {
    //        console.log(anime.data.title)
    
    var data = {
        "Title (Romaji):": anime.data.title,
        "Title (English):": anime.data.title_english,
        "Title (Japanese):": anime.data.title_japanese,
        "MAL ID": anime.data.mal_id,
        "Title Synonyms:": anime.data.title_synonyms,
        "Type": anime.data.type,
        "Source:": anime.data.source,
        "Status:": anime.data.status,
        "Duration:": anime.data.duration,
        "Rating:": anime.data.rating,
        "Score:": anime.data.score,
    "Rank": anime.data.rank,
        "Popularity:": anime.data.popularity,
        "Members:": anime.data.members,
        "Favorites": anime.data.favorites,
        "Premiered:": anime.data.premiered,
        "Broadcast:": anime.data.broadcast,
        "Genres:": anime.data.genres,
        "\n": "\n",
    
      }
      console.log(columnify(data, {columns: ['  ', '    ']}))
      console.log(chalk.green("Synopsis:"))
      console.log(anime.data.synopsis)
      console.log(`\n`)
         })
```

So Basically I'm Showing JSON Objects in the CLI, First Off here is the json file i'm currently using for this example

```
{
    "request_hash": "request:anime:06c1f9aadcb4e3286fa86947ba8451bfc8c6d3a7",
    "request_cached": true,
    "request_cache_expiry": 73254,
    "mal_id": 22663,
    "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/22663/Seiken_Tsukai_no_World_Break",
    "image_url": "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/7/71769.jpg",
    "trailer_url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zGXx54r4yWU?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1",
    "title": "Seiken Tsukai no World Break",
    "title_english": "World Break: Aria of Curse for a Holy Swordsman",
    "title_japanese": "聖剣使いの禁呪詠唱〈ワールドブレイク〉",
    "title_synonyms": [
      "Seiken Tsukai no Kinshuu Eishou",
      "Warubure"
    ],
    "type": "TV",
    "source": "Light novel",
    "episodes": 12,
    "status": "Finished Airing",
    "airing": false,
    "aired": {
      "from": "2015-01-12T00:00:00+00:00",
      "to": "2015-03-30T00:00:00+00:00",
      "prop": {
        "from": {
          "day": 12,
          "month": 1,
          "year": 2015
        },
        "to": {
          "day": 30,
          "month": 3,
          "year": 2015
        }
      },
      "string": "Jan 12, 2015 to Mar 30, 2015"
    },
    "duration": "24 min per ep",
    "rating": "R - 17+ (violence & profanity)",
    "score": 6.93,
    "scored_by": 117100,
    "rank": 3889,
    "popularity": 602,
    "members": 228214,
    "favorites": 813,
    "synopsis": "Seiken Tsukai no World Break takes place at Akane Private Academy where students who possess memories of their previous lives are being trained to use Ancestral Arts so that they can serve as defenders against monsters, called Metaphysicals, who randomly attack. Known as saviors, the students are broken up into two categories: the kurogane who are able to use their prana to summon offensive weapons and the kuroma who are able to use magic. The story begins six months prior to the major climax of the series during the opening ceremonies on the first day of the school year. After the ceremony is over, the main character, Moroha Haimura, meets a girl named Satsuki Ranjou who reveals that she was Moroha's little sister in a past life where Moroha was a heroic prince capable of slaying entire armies with his sword skills. Soon afterwards he meets another girl, Shizuno Urushibara, who eventually reveals that she also knew Moroha in an entirely different past life where he was a dark lord capable of using destructive magic but saved her from a life of slavery. Can those whose minds live in both the present and the past truly reach a bright future? Delve into the complex world of Seiken Tsukai no World Break to find out!",
    "background": null,
    "premiered": "Winter 2015",
    "broadcast": "Mondays at 01:05 (JST)",
    "related": {
      "Adaptation": [
        {
          "mal_id": 57101,
          "type": "manga",
          "name": "Seiken Tsukai no World Break",
          "url": "https://myanimelist.net/manga/57101/Seiken_Tsukai_no_World_Break"
        }
      ]
    },
    "producers": [
      {
        "mal_id": 64,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Sotsu",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/64/Sotsu"
      }
    ],
    "licensors": [
      {
        "mal_id": 102,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Funimation",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/102/Funimation"
      }
    ],
    "studios": [
      {
        "mal_id": 51,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Diomedea",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/51/Diomedea"
      }
    ],
    "genres": [
      {
        "mal_id": 1,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Action",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/1/Action"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 10,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Fantasy",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/10/Fantasy"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 35,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Harem",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/35/Harem"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 22,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Romance",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/22/Romance"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 23,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "School",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/23/School"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 37,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Supernatural",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/37/Supernatural"
      }
    ],
    "opening_themes": [
      "\"Hi no Ito Rinne no Gemini (緋ノ糸輪廻ノGEMINI)\" by petit milady (eps 2-11)"
    ],
    "ending_themes": [
      "#1: \"Hi no Ito Rinne no Gemini (緋ノ糸輪廻ノGEMINI)\" by petit milady (ep 1)",
      "#2: \"Magna Idea (マグナ・イデア)\" by fortuna (フォルトゥーナ) [Satsuki Ranjou (Ayana Taketatsu), Shizuno Urushibara (Aoi Yuuki), Haruka Momochi (Maaya Uchida), and Maya Shimon (Yui Ogura)] (eps 2-12)"
    ]
  }
```

And The Part I'm Stuck On is the Genres Section because it has Multiple Genres with the Same Keys and I Don't Know how to Dynamically Display all of then in one Line of Text or one Sentence Rather

Here is the Genres Section of the JS:

```
"genres": [
      {
        "mal_id": 1,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Action",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/1/Action"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 10,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Fantasy",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/10/Fantasy"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 35,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Harem",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/35/Harem"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 22,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Romance",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/22/Romance"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 23,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "School",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/23/School"
      },
      {
        "mal_id": 37,
        "type": "anime",
        "name": "Supernatural",
        "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/37/Supernatural"
      }
    ],
```

So Here is The Question, How Do I Display All The Genres Like This " Genres:     Action, Fantasy, Harem, Romance, School, Supernatural "? and Have it Display like this if There are more genres than these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a string with the names of the genres, you could use `.map()` and `.join()`. Use `.map()` to turn the array into an array of genre names, from an array of objects. Then use `.join()` to combine the array into a string.

```js
var data = {
  "request_hash": "request:anime:06c1f9aadcb4e3286fa86947ba8451bfc8c6d3a7",
  "request_cached": true,
  "request_cache_expiry": 73254,
  "mal_id": 22663,
  "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/22663/Seiken_Tsukai_no_World_Break",
  "image_url": "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/7/71769.jpg",
  "trailer_url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zGXx54r4yWU?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1",
  "title": "Seiken Tsukai no World Break",
  "title_english": "World Break: Aria of Curse for a Holy Swordsman",
  "title_japanese": "聖剣使いの禁呪詠唱〈ワールドブレイク〉",
  "title_synonyms": [
    "Seiken Tsukai no Kinshuu Eishou",
    "Warubure"
  ],
  "type": "TV",
  "source": "Light novel",
  "episodes": 12,
  "status": "Finished Airing",
  "airing": false,
  "aired": {
    "from": "2015-01-12T00:00:00+00:00",
    "to": "2015-03-30T00:00:00+00:00",
    "prop": {
      "from": {
        "day": 12,
        "month": 1,
        "year": 2015
      },
      "to": {
        "day": 30,
        "month": 3,
        "year": 2015
      }
    },
    "string": "Jan 12, 2015 to Mar 30, 2015"
  },
  "duration": "24 min per ep",
  "rating": "R - 17+ (violence & profanity)",
  "score": 6.93,
  "scored_by": 117100,
  "rank": 3889,
  "popularity": 602,
  "members": 228214,
  "favorites": 813,
  "synopsis": "Seiken Tsukai no World Break takes place at Akane Private Academy where students who possess memories of their previous lives are being trained to use Ancestral Arts so that they can serve as defenders against monsters, called Metaphysicals, who randomly attack. Known as saviors, the students are broken up into two categories: the kurogane who are able to use their prana to summon offensive weapons and the kuroma who are able to use magic. The story begins six months prior to the major climax of the series during the opening ceremonies on the first day of the school year. After the ceremony is over, the main character, Moroha Haimura, meets a girl named Satsuki Ranjou who reveals that she was Moroha's little sister in a past life where Moroha was a heroic prince capable of slaying entire armies with his sword skills. Soon afterwards he meets another girl, Shizuno Urushibara, who eventually reveals that she also knew Moroha in an entirely different past life where he was a dark lord capable of using destructive magic but saved her from a life of slavery. Can those whose minds live in both the present and the past truly reach a bright future? Delve into the complex world of Seiken Tsukai no World Break to find out!",
  "background": null,
  "premiered": "Winter 2015",
  "broadcast": "Mondays at 01:05 (JST)",
  "related": {
    "Adaptation": [{
      "mal_id": 57101,
      "type": "manga",
      "name": "Seiken Tsukai no World Break",
      "url": "https://myanimelist.net/manga/57101/Seiken_Tsukai_no_World_Break"
    }]
  },
  "producers": [{
    "mal_id": 64,
    "type": "anime",
    "name": "Sotsu",
    "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/64/Sotsu"
  }],
  "licensors": [{
    "mal_id": 102,
    "type": "anime",
    "name": "Funimation",
    "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/102/Funimation"
  }],
  "studios": [{
    "mal_id": 51,
    "type": "anime",
    "name": "Diomedea",
    "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/producer/51/Diomedea"
  }],
  "genres": [{
      "mal_id": 1,
      "type": "anime",
      "name": "Action",
      "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/1/Action"
    },
    {
      "mal_id": 10,
      "type": "anime",
      "name": "Fantasy",
      "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/10/Fantasy"
    },
    {
      "mal_id": 35,
      "type": "anime",
      "name": "Harem",
      "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/35/Harem"
    },
    {
      "mal_id": 22,
      "type": "anime",
      "name": "Romance",
      "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/22/Romance"
    },
    {
      "mal_id": 23,
      "type": "anime",
      "name": "School",
      "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/23/School"
    },
    {
      "mal_id": 37,
      "type": "anime",
      "name": "Supernatural",
      "url": "https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/37/Supernatural"
    }
  ],
  "opening_themes": [
    "\"Hi no Ito Rinne no Gemini (緋ノ糸輪廻ノGEMINI)\" by petit milady (eps 2-11)"
  ],
  "ending_themes": [
    "#1: \"Hi no Ito Rinne no Gemini (緋ノ糸輪廻ノGEMINI)\" by petit milady (ep 1)",
    "#2: \"Magna Idea (マグナ・イデア)\" by fortuna (フォルトゥーナ) [Satsuki Ranjou (Ayana Taketatsu), Shizuno Urushibara (Aoi Yuuki), Haruka Momochi (Maaya Uchida), and Maya Shimon (Yui Ogura)] (eps 2-12)"
  ]
}

console.log(data.genres.map(e => e.name).join(", "))
```